# Delete white spaces by pattern regex

Tags: python

I tried to remove the white spaces of some strings, as below

```
import re
test_str = '''PERSON_ID<|>DEPT_ID<|>DATE_JOINED
    AAAAA<|>S1<|>2021/01/03
    BBBBBB<|>S2<|>
    2021/02/03
    CCCCC<|>S1<|>2021/03/05'''

regex = r's*<|>s*\<|>s*\n+'
subst = "<|>"
# print(re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE).split('\n'))
for line in re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE).split('\n'):
    # print(line)
    if line != '':
        print (line.strip())
```

I've got the output,

```
PERSON_ID<|>|>DEPT_ID<|>|>DATE_JOINED
AAAAA<|>|>S1<|>|>2021/01/03
BBBBBB<|>|>S2<|>|<|>    2021/02/03
CCCCC<|>|>S1<|>|>2021/03/05
```

I am looking for a solution to remove the white spaces in the second last line before the date in the output.

Comment: What if `\n2021/02/03` is a valid "cell" in your data?

Comment: Why does your output have an extra `|>` for each column?

Comment: Do you even need regexes at all? Looks like this is just tabular data split with `<|>|>`. Split the lines, strip the cells, and glue them back however you want them

Comment: Why do you need `re.MULTILINE`? The regexp doesn't have any `^` or `$` in it.

Comment: Is `s*` supposed to be `\s*`?

Comment: @Alexander It looks like the issue is that the 3rd and 4th lines should be combined, so it's not purely tabular.

Comment: It supposes to be tabular data but with some human errors. If I split them by lines, how can I put them back?

Comment: @Barmar, if I change it to `regex = r's*\s*\s*\n+` , the output still has the white spaces:  `PERSON_ID<|>DEPT_ID<|>DATE_JOINED<|>    AAAAA<|>S1<|>2021/01/03<|>    BBBBBB<|>S2<|><|>    2021/02/03<|>    CCCCC<|>S1<|>2021/03/05`

Comment: Regex isn't the correct solution here as it cannot guarantee the final output will preserve the three columns, and won't account for all other cases where there could be whitespace in each row

Comment: PERSON_ID<|>DEPT_ID<|>DATE_JOINED
AAAAA<|>S1<|>2021/01/03
BBBBBB<|>S2<|>2021/02/03
CCCCC<|>S1<|>2021/03/05

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `\n+` after `>\s*`. So it stops removing whitespace at the `\n`, and leaves the spaces at the beginning of the next line. Change that to `>\s+`, since newline is included in whitespace.

```
import re
test_str = '''PERSON_ID<|>DEPT_ID<|>DATE_JOINED
    AAAAA<|>S1<|>2021/01/03
    BBBBBB<|>S2<|>
    2021/02/03
    CCCCC<|>S1<|>2021/03/05'''

regex = r'\s+<|>\s+<|>\s+'
subst = "<|>"
# print(re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE).split('\n'))
for line in re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE).split('\n'):
    # print(line)
    if line != '':
        print (line.strip())
```

Comment: Yes, it works! :)Thank you*100!

Comment: @Barmar I tried to run the code and the second line looks like: `BBBBBB<|>S2<|<|>2021/02/03`. Is there an extra `<|` after `52`

Comment: Your regexp matches both single `>` and `<` as well as `><`. It replaces all of them with `<|>`

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd try a solution that tries to guarantee each row as three columns separated by a common separator, that doesn't depend on regex

Specifically, if you're getting this dataset from an unknown source, then it isn't "regular" and there's no expression that can guarantee its always the date column that needs fixed

```
test_str = '''PERSON_ID<|>DEPT_ID<|>DATE_JOINED
    AAAAA<|>S1<|>2021/01/03
    BBBBBB<|>S2<|>
    2021/02/03
    CCCCC<|>S1<|>2021/03/05'''

lines = [l.strip() for l in test_str.splitlines(keepends=False)]
sep = '<|>'

def get_columns(line, separator):
  return [x.strip() for x in line.split(separator) if x.strip()]

header = get_columns(lines[0], sep)
columns = len(header)

# prepare case if second line needs to join first line
i = 1
lines[i] = sep.join(get_columns(lines[i], sep))

# check remaining lines
while True:
  i += 1
  if i >= len(lines):
    break
  # print(i, lines[i])
  parts = get_columns(lines[i], sep)
  previous_parts = get_columns(lines[i-1], sep)
  num_parts = len(parts)
  # skip lines that shouldn't be relocated
  if num_parts == columns or len(previous_parts) == columns:
    continue
  else:
    if len(parts) + len(previous_parts) > columns:
      # TODO: handle case where this line has all columns and part of the previous line
      pass  
    previous_parts.extend(parts)
    lines[i-1] = sep.join(previous_parts)
    del lines[i]  # remove the current line that was moved to the previous

for l in lines:
  print(l)
```

Sample output

```
PERSON_ID<|>DEPT_ID<|>DATE_JOINED
AAAAA<|>S1<|>2021/01/03
BBBBBB<|>S2<|>2021/02/03
CCCCC<|>S1<|>2021/03/05
```

Same output for

```
test_str = '''PERSON_ID<|>DEPT_ID<|>DATE_JOINED
    AAAAA<|>S1<|>
    2021/01/03
    BBBBBB<|>S2<|>
    2021/02/03
    CCCCC<|>S1<|>2021/03/05'''
```

and

```
test_str = '''PERSON_ID<|>DEPT_ID<|>DATE_JOINED
    AAAAA<|>
    S1<|>2021/01/03
    BBBBBB<|>S2<|>
    2021/02/03
    CCCCC<|>S1<|>2021/03/05'''
```